# summing dict values up to a threshold - itertools.takewhile?

Tags: python, python-itertools

A problem that frequently occurs in stochastic simulation is calculating which of several events occurs.  This is typically done by having a probability for each event.  Then generating a random number and then iterating through the possible events until finding where the sum of their probabilities exceeds the random number.

Here is code that does what I want, but I'm after a better way to do it.

```
import random

def getEvent(eventProbabilities,probability):
    S = 0
    for key in eventProbabilities.keys():
        S += eventProbabilities[key]
        if S>= probability:   #key is the event to happen.
            break
    return key

x = {'event1' : 0.1 , 'event2' : 0.2 , 'event3' : 0.2 , 'event4' : 0.4, 'event5' : 0.1} #values sum to 1.
p = random.random()  #random number between 0 and 1.
event = getEvent(x,p)
print p, event
```

I feel like there's got to be a more compact way to define getEvent - likely using `takewhile` - but I can't find it.

I'm after maximum efficiency, because I think this is where my code is going to spend most of its time.

Is there a way to make this more efficient through itertools (or otherwise)?

**Edit added below to comment on whether we care about the order of iteration.**

You'll notice that the keys will be processed in some order.  That order is independent of the random number p.  Let's consider the case where it processes them in the order I listed them.  If `p<=0.1` then it will return `event1`  So with 10% chance it's event1.  If `0.1<p<0.3` it'll return `event2` (so 20% probability).  Now lets consider a different order.  Say it goes in reverse order.  In this case if `0.9<p` we'll get `event1` (10%), while if `0.7<p<=0.9` we get `event2` (again 20%).  So the probabilities of each event are the same, regardless of the order.

I just want to select 1 event, and I want that event selected with the corresponding probability.

Comment: Is the order of events important here?

Comment: If you're asking about it iterating through the keys in an unknown order, that's not a problem.     (though I guess if it were to iterate through in decreasing order by probability that would speed things up, but I probably won't know that order in advance)

Comment: And you want the event at which we exceed the threshold?

Comment: Right.  So if p=0.14 and it iterates through with event5, then event3, it would stop and return event3.

Comment: How do you know that it processed `event5` before `event3`? Doesn't that matter to you?

Comment: I don't care about the order that the keys are iterated through.  That was just an example.  As long as the choice of p is independent of the order, I don't care what order it processes them, I just want the event where it exceeds the threshold.  I'll edit the question to explain a bit better

Comment: Why not sort by the values, itertate till threshold, then lookup the event name?

Comment: If numpy is an option, its [`random.choice()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) is likely to be more efficient than any hand-rolled solution.

Comment: @burhan Each time I do this, the values will be different.  So I'll still have to do the iteration (it might be quicker), but I'll have to sort first.

Comment: @joel - you mean `x` will be different at each iteration?

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus That looks hopeful.  Would there be a fast way to handle the fact that each time the values are different?  I'd like to avoid going through all values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you simply want to select an element from a list with a given probability. Why not use `numpy`?

```
>>> x = {'event1': 0.1 , 'event2': 0.2 , 'event3': 0.2 , 'event4': 0.4, 
         'event5': 0.1}
>>> events, p = zip(*x.items())
>>> np.random.choice(events, p=p, replace=False)
'event4'
```

Comment: This may be my best option (I wasn't aware numpy handled variable probabilities).  I'd have to generate the list fresh each time I go through this because the values (and even number of keys) would change.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Joel I see... I'm afraid not, as `np.random.choice` requires array-like inputs of already computed probabilities. Do you need to calculate all probabilities a priori to compute a normalization factor? Or can you produce the correctly normalized probabilities one-at-a-time?

Comment: I can generate them one at a time correctly.  Depending on the problem I'm simulating (this comes up frequently), sometimes I have everything in advance.

Comment: @Joel Well, in that case it would seem like going back to a pure python implementation would work best, as you could do essentially what you have in your question, computing the probabilities for each event only as you need them. You say you're worried about efficiency... if the probabilities themselves are expensive to compute, the `for`-loop you'll write to sum them and compute the threshold won't be noticeable. Unless, of course, you have some events which are expensive to compute, and many, many events which are cheap.

Comment: Thanks - I'll do the pure python for those cases, and then use this for the rest.  Using numpy should be a pretty dramatic speed up when it's doable.